# What are the new features of ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I just installed 13.04 from (12.10) graphics are great except the dropdown folder feature is gone.There was no preview about what changes there are and I thought is was a software update..like of the ones that appear when opening firefox. now there is now feature in the help menu for new features. I also cannot find anything online.
Help, I am afraid I SHOULD NOT have installed the upgrade.

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: Of course you should have installed it. Always have the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal; by `lsb_release` you can check your Ubuntu version. the other way at the right-top corner of the screen open 'corg' and select `About this Computer`. You will see your ubutu release version.

You can also check the new features of Ubutnu 13.04 [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes#New_features_in_13.04).